# Determinant of complex matrix with almost constant lines

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, inverse

Let $0\neq c\in\mathbb{C}$. Take the matrix 
$$A_C=\begin{pmatrix}
n&c&\dots&c&c \\
c&n&c &\dots & c\\
c &c & n &c &\dots\\
\vdots &\vdots&\vdots&\ddots & \vdots \\
c & \dots &\dots &c& n
\end{pmatrix}\in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}.$$

I want to show that $A_C$ invertible. It seems like one can compute the determinant explicitly but I messed with it a bit.

How can I prove $\det A_C\neq 0$?

**EDIT:** We assume $c\neq n$.

Comment: You can't prove this at that level of generality. Consider the singular matrix $\begin{pmatrix}2 & 1 \\ 4 & 2\end{pmatrix}$ which has the desired structure.

Comment: @frog thanks. what about the case in which $c_i=c_j\forall i,j$ (the question was editted appropriately) ?

Comment: Is $n=c$ in the matrix

Comment: @ArchisWelankar Assume $c\neq n$.

Comment: In general you have to make sure that $c$ will avoid zeros of certain polynomials. For example you find $\det(A_4)=-3c^4+32c^3-96c^2+256$ and if $c$ is a zero of this polynomial, your matrix will be singular. Maybe you find a general pattern for the polynomial. I guess something like $$\det (A_c)=(-1)^{n+1}(n-1)c^n+(-1)^nn^2(n-2)c^{n-1}+\cdots$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a circulant matrix and as such has normalized eigenvectors
$$v_j=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(1,\omega_j,\omega_j^2,\ldots,\omega_j^{n-1})$$
where
$$\omega_j=exp\left(\frac{2\pi i j}{n}\right)$$
The eigenvalues are
$$\lambda_j=n+c\omega_j+c\omega_j^2+\cdots+c\omega_j^{n-1}$$
Taking the product of the eigen values gives the determinant. Now since the $\omega_j$ are roots of unity we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\omega_j^k=-1$$
which gives
$\lambda_j=n-c$. Since we have assumed that $n\neq c$ no eigenvalue is equal to zero. Hence the determinant is non-zero.

Comment: Why is $\lambda_j \neq 0$, or equivalently $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\omega_j^i \neq -1$?

Comment: The author assumes that $n \neq c$

Answer (score -1):

See if its so take it in eigenvalues. We know that sum of eigenvalues is the trace of matrix  as $n \neq  c $ is not equal to $0$ so we can easily conclude that $det(A) \neq 0$ you can also do that as $det(A)=π \lambda_i$ and as $n\neq 0$ so the determinant is also non-zero and its done.

Comment: I don't see how you can "easily conclude that $\det A \neq 0$". You seem to be claiming that $\sum a_i \neq 0$ implies that $\prod a_i \neq 0$, which is not true in general. By the way, your first sentence is incomprehensible.